# How to track the position of the second pointer

Tags: c#, wpf

I will like to know what can I do to track down the position of a second pointer which enter in the canvas.
I added a counter in the PointerEntered event handler. It's able to track how many pointers are there, but I don't know how to track the position of the second(or more) pointer as it moves.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I assume each pointer is represented by an object. So can't you store the current position as a property of the object ?

Comment: @Nitesh Yes that's right. I don't want the property to be fixed to that only current position which had been capture when it entered the canvas. As the second pointer moves, I want that property of the second pointer to be updated as well.

Comment: So you can do that, just update CurrentPosition property of pointer objects in your pointer moving logic.

Comment: @Nitesh The event handler "PointerMoved" gives back a current position like what you mention, but it's been assigned to pointer1. If I assign that "currentposition" to pointer2, pointer1 will become 0, 0. So it becomes updating different property rather than updating different property individually which is what I want.

Comment: Yes so you need some mathematics there to calculate new position for other pointers from current mouse position.

Comment: @Nitesh Oh, it might work ! Thank you ! (:

Comment: @Nitesh Is there any examples anywhere that I can reference to ?

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding event provides event arguments that hold a reference to the `Pointer`. Each pointer instance has a separate pointer id:
[Pointer Properties on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointer#properties)

You need to also register with the [`PointerMoved`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointermoved.aspx) event to get updates of the pointer location. Using the pointer ids, you can index into your local data structure to update the location of your visual on the canvas.

You cannot register for the events bound to a specific pointer ID. All events will be triggered for all pointers. So you only register once with the events, normally. You need to keep track (e.g. via a `Dictionary` from pointer id to your pointer data) of each pointer in your own code if you need to handle each pointer input differently. The [MSDN Pointer Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150606.aspx) has a nice example that shows exactly that.

Comment: So do you mean that assign one pointer id to each pointer, and register PointerMoved event to each pointer. Am I right to say that ?

Comment: @LTaylor: I updated my answer - basically, the answer is: No, because you cannot.